# Using jQuery UI Dialoge Box in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-dialog

Existing Dialog box feature of jQuery mobile requires, new hyperlink to open.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

I want something exactly like jQuery UI Dialoge box, I tried this with jQuery-Mobile. It is not working correctly at the moment. (dialoge box is looking transparent and not UI theme is not being applied of jQuery-Mobile. What all we can do to make it look like jQuery Mobile dialog box.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you spend time trying to use jQuery UI's dialog widget here are a few important facts:

1. jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile don't play well together because of some class conflicts.
2. Since you are using jQuery Mobile I'm guessing this is a mobile website, in which case you want to make it as light as possible; adding the code-weight of jQuery UI (JS + CSS) is almost certainly overkill.
3. jQuery Mobile will be including a `popup` widget in the 1.1 release (which should be coming soon): http://filamentgroup.com/tests/popup/docs/pages/popup/index.html

I suggest using the widgets that are baked into jQuery Mobile, the dialog widget works pretty well at the moment and should only be more stable in the future.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. This should be the way to go as you suggested. but From where would I get the latest jQuery mobile code (I did view-source of the page you suggested, but didn't get any clue from there. ) I also tried latest jquerymobile on CDN, but no success.

Comment: The jQuery Mobile team should be releasing an update (version 1.1) any day now. I would suggest waiting for that so you can use a stable version. Otherwise the `dialog` widget from jQuery Mobile should work fine if you don't include the jQuery UI files in your document.